# Flags in different chatrooms

Tags: support, status-bydesign, chat, flags

I recently noticed that I get notifications about flags from chatrooms where I'm not a room owner. Now I'm not sure about whether this is intended or not but I feel like it doesn't really make any sense.

The only room where I'm currently listed as a room owner is [Summoners Rift](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2348/summoners-rift) (our League of Legends Chatroom) but I got notifications about flags from the [Mathematics Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) which doesn't make any sense to me (I don't even have an account on Mathematics.SE).

Now my questions are:

1. Is this working as intended or is this a bug?
2. Can I disable these notifications if they come from rooms where I'm not an owner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is working as intended
2. No, other than with a userscript to hide them.

All 10k users see *all* flags raised anywhere in chat.

Answer (score 1):

Chat flags are shown to *all* users in any room with more than 10k aggregate reputation across the network. Room ownership has nothing to do with it.

They can't be turned off, but they tend to get resolved reasonably quickly if you just want to ignore them and not participate in chat moderation.

Comment: I like how we both italicised *all*.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as intended. You have enough rep now to be considered a chat mod, as it were, and thus see all notifications for flags in rooms SE wide (with exceptions for SO rooms, and M.SE rooms, I believe).

As far as I know, there is no way to turn these notifications off, but you don't have to take any action if you don't wish to - there are enough people with this ability that the flags usually get handled pretty fast.

Comment: Flags are usually handled before I can even *react*.